# VLC aspect ratio instable

Tags: vlc

On the same HDMI monitor, the screen aspect ratio of a movie changes when switching to full-screen.

How to maintain the same aspect ration between full-screen or not?

- Raspbian, PI 3 B+
- VLC media player 3.0.6 Vetinari

Comment: Is the aspect ratio of the screen the same as the aspect ratio of the movie? If not, how should it be preserved and at the same time use the full screen?

Comment: of coarse it should be preserved, but it changes.

Comment: As in full-screen the cursor disappears in this version of vlc,
As nothing helps in .config/vlc/vlcrc, file saved and PI rebooted, this make impossible to use vlc.

Tried to install Totem and SMPlayer IN PI: those have hardware
problems, for example the screen is jerky.
Which means either a lack of memory (1GByte in PI3 B+),
or a missing hardware acceleration.

A solution could be to find a VLC source tarball and hope to modify and compile it with such a small memory